# Replicating Matrix-Matrix Multiplication using Tensordot

Tags: python, numpy, tensor, tensordot

In `PyKeops` [package](http://www.kernel-operations.io/keops/api/math-operations.html), there is no available formula for Matrix-Matrix multiplication. Instead, they have implemented something similar to `numpy.tensordot`. I have two matrices `A,B` of size `m x n` and `n x n`. Is there any way to replicate `A @ B` using `numpy.tensordot`.

```py
import numpy as np
m,n = 10, 20
A = np.random.random((m,n))
B = np.random.random((n,n))

result1 = A @ B
result2 = np.tensordot(A,B,(1,1))

print(result1 == result2)

# =======================
# array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, 
# ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found an answer to this, we can fix this using the following parameters given to `tensordot`:

```py
import numpy as np
m,n = 10, 20
A = np.random.random((m,n))
B = np.random.random((n,n))

result1 = A @ B
result2 = np.tensordot(A,B,[(1,),(0,)])

print(result1 == result2)

# =======================
# array([[True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, 
# ....
```